# Shopify: How can I render the recommended products?

Tags: ajax, shopify, liquid

I am trying to use Shopify Ajax API to get recommended products inside the cart. I am able to get the recommended product's json but not the section rendering.

The script (note `section_id`):

```
 jQuery.getJSON('/cart.js', function(cart) {
      // first recommendation
      jQuery.getJSON("/recommendations/products.json?product_id=" + cart.items[0].product_id + "&limit=6&section_id=recommended_first", function(
       response
      ) {
       var recommendedProducts = response.products;
       }
      });
    })
```

The HTML:

```
<div id="recommended_first" class="upsell_product">
     
</div>
```

I get some messages in the console:

> Error: ShopifyAnalytics.meta.page.pageType is empty: undefined

> Fallback logic initiated

What am I missing? I didn't find any examples in the Shopify doc.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: So recommendedProducts contains all the correct data? How are you outputing that into the actual page?

Comment: @cMarius I don't know how to output it as HTML, but only as json. I got the code from [here](https://shopify.dev/docs/themes/ajax-api/reference/product-recommendations ).

Answer (score 0):

Your code will not work because you have an extra `}` on line 7. Assuming the cart request returns valid data, the following code should work (also a good idea to check if the cart request returns any items before using the `cart.items` variable):

```
jQuery.getJSON('/cart.js', function(cart) {
    jQuery.getJSON("/recommendations/products.json?product_id=" + cart?.items?[0]?.product_id + "&limit=6&section_id=recommended_first", function(response) {
        var recommendedProducts = response.products;
        var recommendedProductsHTML = "";

        for (i = 0; i < recommendedProducts.length; i++) {
            recommendedProductsHTML += `<div>${recommendedProducts[i].title}</div>`;
        }

        $("#recommended_first").html(recommendedProductsHTML);
    });
});
```